# Where did the concept of field come from?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, field-theory, history, vector-fields

What made scientists start to think about what was previously 'forces-exerted-by' (Newtonian view) to fields (e.g. electric fields and magnetic fields)?

Comment: FWIW, I was trying to work this out earlier today for another question. I found a claim that Faraday first used the term "field" in relation to electrostatics. I couldn't find any reference to who first applied it to magnetism (if that was done before Maxwell brought E & M together).

Comment: More history of science?

Comment: You may be interested in the site [hsm.se]

Answer (score 4):

The concept of field lines originated with Michael Faraday, who didn't have sufficient mathematical background to understand how brilliant it was.

I have only skimmed this article, but it appears well researched and seems to address your question:  [Origins of the Field Concept in Physics, by Ernan McMullin PDF](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6e91/f808b354f63a1bf6c1320a9514ec3bdaf571.pdf).  My reason for nominating Faraday is that I was addressing the concept of a field as a "*form of matter*" as Hans Ohanian puts it.  The concept of field in fluid dynamics is more mathematical than physical.

Comment: I found the article by Ernan McMullin very informative, I recommend reading it. In retrospect we can see that in trying to understand the world the researchers were very reluctant to introduce a concept of a field that participates in physics taking place. That is what occurred to me over the course of reading that article: a reluctance to introduce a field concept, so much so that I now wonder why eventually it *was* introduced.

Answer (score 2):

Scientists needed a theory to explain why forces could be conducted through a vacuum.  There is nothing inside the vacuum (i.e. no mass) and therefore only a field concept can explain why an electrostatic or magnetic force or even gravitational force and be transmitted through "nothing".